# How can I pass union/intersection methods as a parameter in Python?

Tags: python, parameter-passing

Can I pass the union and intersection methods of the [Set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) Python class as an argument?

I am searching for direct way to do this, without using additional lambda or regular functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methods are first-class objects, just like other functions. You can pass it bound:

```
x = set([1,2,3])
my_function(x.union)
```

or unbound

```
my_function(set.union)
```

as necessary.

Example:

```
def test(s1, s2, op):
    return op(s1,s2)

test(set([1]), set([2]), set.union)  # set([1, 2])
```